# Reading Invalid Data c6385

Tags: c++, function, pointers, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

I am a newbie and I am basically just making a text based game at the moment.

I have a function, but it seems to alter the wrong elements of the array.

```cpp
void petStatRead(int statArr[5][7], int* iDPnt, string creature){
    int petID = *iDPnt;
    int LVL = statArr[0][6];
    cout << creature << "'s current Level is: " << LVL << endl;
    int EXP = statArr[0][7];
    cout << creature << "'s current EXP is: " << EXP << endl;
}
```

Instead of outputting `[0][6]`, it outputs `[0][7]`, and so on.

I get this error:

> C6385 Reading invalid data from 'statArr[0]':  the readable size is '28' bytes, but '32' bytes may be read.

`[0][6]` is supposed to store a `1`, while the other stores a `0`.

But it outputs `0`, then `1`.

I am beyond lost, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Accessing `statArr[0][7]` makes your program have undefined behavior (even though you probably get the output from `[1][0]`).

Comment: Array indexes are 0-based, so the valid indexes for your `statArr` array are: `statArr[0][0]..statArr[0][6]`, `statArr[1][0]..statArr[1][6]`, ... `statArr[4][0]..statArr[4][6]`. So accessing `statArr[0][7]` is technically out of bounds of the 1st `int[7]` array located at `statArr[0]`, it reaches into the 1st `int` of the 2nd `int[7]` array located at `statArr[1]`.

Comment: Why are you even storing this data in an array? If you're storing data about level next to data about experience, you're almost certainly better of creating a struct/class with fields `m_experience` and `m_level`.